# C++ template subclass of a base w/o a template. How to extract template info thru base?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

More of my toy code is here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/976e31bf360d7d15

```
struct DynamicInterface
{
    virtual ~DynamicInterface() = default;
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual TypeCode type() const = 0;   

    // I wish I could do this , but template member functions cannot be virtual
    // due to compile time vs runtime requirements for templates vs virtual methods.
    // virtual template<typename T> std::vector<T>::iterator begin() = 0; 
    // virtual template<typename T> std::vector<T>::iterator end() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class DynamicVector : public DynamicInterface
{
public:
    ~DynamicVector<T>() override = default;
    DynamicVector<T>(const std::vector<T>& vec, const TypeCode type) : vec_(vec), type_(type) {}
    size_t size() const override { return vec_.size(); }
    TypeCode type() const override { return type_; }
    T& operator[](size_t n) { return vec_[n]; }

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin() {return vec_.begin(); }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end() {return vec_.end(); }

    private:
        std::vector<T> vec_;
        TypeCode type_;
};
```

More specifically, I have a lightweight interface without template parameters.  Subclassing that is a template class that contains a std::vector.

I wish that I could make a templatized virtual method in order to access the encapsulated vector's iterators in the subclass through a pointer to the interface.

I suspect I am well and truly F$%@ed if this is what I want to do, but I was wondering if there are any clever tricks that people can do to pull this off or coerce the compiler into doing something close to what I want - C++ really requires acrobatics sometimes

Comment: Suppose you have a `DynamicInterface* ifc;`. If it were possible, how would you intend to do anything useful with an element like `*ifc->begin()` without knowing what type it is?

Comment: Knowing that you can't do this, ask yourself: "What's the real problem I am trying to solve?" Language features are only the means to an end. Understanding the end well might reveal other language features you can use to get there.

Comment: @RSahu As in the toy code at coliru, I am trying to make a DataFrame like class.  I actually created one already that has cells that are comprised of encapsulated boost::variant objects and that works beautifully.  My colleague was pushing back by noting that columns are not typesafe enough because one could change the cells from int to string or whatever easily and muck things up - so he recommended this kind of approach to harden the types in the frame columns (through boost::optional for nulls). Then I hit these kinds of roadblocks and I think my original approach is better now.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode, I looked at your code and can't come with anything clever. Hope some one else can. Best of luck.

Comment: @RSahu thx for looking.  I will argue for run time type checking the boost::variant in my original implementation to insure column type integrity and that will slow things down a bit, but this should still be a big productivity enhancer for me to crush through mountains of options data.  The boost::variant methodology allows me to have a proper strongly typed return type to a lot of my functions at the cost of some runtime type checks - should still be faster than Python dataframes and can be put to more industrial use cases.

Comment: I am guessing you want to use this to remove the 'case's in your print method. If that is so why not let the specializations print themselves. Sure it would not be vertical (your printed table) by default but you can fix it up. You can also make the specializations return an element by index. Then you can pretty much print them as you want.

Comment: Something like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b315ca15ad99bd80

Comment: Or printing by index like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49a557ab11064fa7

Comment: Thx stardust.  Yes that works well for printing which returns void, but the printing in my example was mostly to show what my container has.  Ultimately, iterators are what I want to plug into algorithms like a lexicographic sorter etc through std::sort and a functor of my choosing.  Stuff like that and more.  I may stick with my old solution of using boost::variant..or god forbid...6 different unordered_maps with one for each type (Date and DateTime and bool) are the other main types I would use.  The vector<boost::variant> give a clean return type for the iterators, but it has its flaws too.

Comment: @aschepler - incidentally, I do have the types at run time - that is known which I guess was why I was hoping to use templates at run time, but of course, they are strictly compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to make your interface very generic, such that it could serve as the interface for all of your child classes. This is still possible to achieve through templates if you're willing to make the parent a template class (not sure if that's what you're looking for).

Then you can use the subclass' template typename to specialize the inheritance. Like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
struct TypeCode {};
template <typename T> struct DynamicInterface {
    virtual ~DynamicInterface() = default;
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual TypeCode type() const = 0;
    virtual typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual typename std::vector<T>::iterator end() = 0;
};
template <typename T> struct DynamicVector : public DynamicInterface<T> {
public:
    ~DynamicVector<T>() override = default;
    DynamicVector<T>(const std::vector<T>& vec, const TypeCode type) : vec_(vec), type_(type) {}
    size_t size() const override { return vec_.size(); }
    TypeCode type() const override { return type_; }
    T& operator[](size_t n) { return vec_[n]; }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin() {return vec_.begin(); }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end() {return vec_.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<T> vec_;
    TypeCode type_;
};

int main() {
  TypeCode t;
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
  DynamicVector<int> d(v, t);
  std::cout << "begin: " << *d.begin() << "\n";
  std::cout << "end: " << *(d.end() - 1) << "\n";
}
```

And this will give you the output:

```
begin: 1
end: 2
```